# How to refresh access_token in OAuth 2.0 in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am developing a salesforce app and using OAuth 2.0 to login. I have a refresh token; how do I get a new access_token by sending a request to salesforce via OAuth 2.0 containing the refresh token for a particular user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taken from "[Digging Deeper into Oauth 2.0 on Force.com](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)", your application can obtain a new access token by POSTing another request to: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token.  The payload should be of the form: grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=[your client id]&client_secret=[your client secret]&refresh_token=[the user's refresh token].

Comment: When I ask for the new access token by sending refresh token, it sends the old one access_token only in response. So next consecutive requests will have the error as INVALID SESSION ID

Comment: I found the issue. In configurations Administration Profile was missing to be connected with Apps whose client ID and secret I was using.