# Salesforce access token expires

Tags: ssis, salesforce

I am pulling SalesForce API records into Sql through MSBI ETL using script task. I'am using the Sales Force access token for the authentication purpose in code. But that access token expires every 12 hrs and I've to manually update the access token before the package execution. 
Please help me out if there any possible way to have permanent Salesforce access token key or how can we generate access token from refresh token from Salesforce API.

Regards,
Mohammed

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a refresh token, please see this question and answer. You still have to periodically get a new refresh token, but that's a much longer interval than the 12 hrs for each access token:

[How to refresh access_token in OAuth 2.0 in salesforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499059/how-to-refresh-access-token-in-oauth-2-0-in-salesforce?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on such scripts, I used to connect the salesforce with api with the Timeout parameter. 
Example lie: SFLogin({TIMEOUT => 900})

Checkout if this helps to you!